# Did <input type=submit /> uses javascript behind the scenes

Tags: php

Did this example of type="submit" have javascript behind the scenes?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value=""/><br />
        Password: <input type="text" name="username" value=""/><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Because the other way to submit your data inputs into server is like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function submit(form){
            form.submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value=""/><br />
        Password: <input type="text" name="username" value=""/><br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit(this.form);" />
    </form>
</body>
```

If so then we dont need javascript to send data into server?? am i right?

Answer (score 6):

If you use `<input type='submit'>`, no need to add JavaScript. In this case browser will submit the form even if JavaScript is disabled.

If you want to submit the form using JavaScript, then you can use the above method you wrote. In this case, you can use any other control and on click you can submit.

So, clearly, `<input type='submit'>` doesn't use any JavaScript.

Comment: so then...javascript is not the only way to send data to server?

Comment: Yes. Browser can submit data even JavaScript is disabled, i.e. without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Your given example does not use javascript to submit data to the server. By default, the submit button sends all info from your form to the server. You may however need javascript to handle things like error checking and posting without requiring a single page reload.

Answer (score 0):

The example mentioned in above code snippet does not use javascript for form submission.
Input button with `type="submit"` when clicked has a default behaviour for submission of form.

So form will be submitted using submit button regardless of Javascript being enabled in browser. Also we can submit form using javascript through the following code snippet

```
document.formName.submit();
```